# about TranslateTransform and RenderTransformOrigin

Tags: c#, .net, animation, silverlight, visual-studio-2008

I am using Silverlight 3.0 + .Net 3.5 + VSTS 2008 + C# to silverlight application.

I want to learn TranslateTransform and RenderTransformOrigin, could anyone recommend me some tutorials? I am a newbie of this area. And I did not find anything which is good to learn for a newbie from MSDN (correct me if there are some good stuff). :-)

BTW: I am headache about the coordination transformation matrix, it is great if the tutorial could cover this topic.

EDIT: here is the code which I am confused.

```
    <Grid Margin="-1,0,100,0" x:Name="controlsContainer" Height="35" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform Y="0"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Rectangle Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="#97000000" Stroke="#00000000" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
        <VideoPlayer:mediaControl Height="35" Margin="1,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="mediaControls" Visibility="Visible"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: "coordination transformation matrix" are you refering to the MatrixTransform?

Comment: I mean the matrix under Remarks section of this MSDN page,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform(v=VS.95).aspx

Appreciate if you could recommend me some good materials for a newbie.

Comment: I have posted my confusions about TranslateTransform and RenderTransformOrigin in EDIT 1 section of my post. Appreciate if you could let me know in order to understand the code I posted, what kinds of tutorials do I need to read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Translate** is specifically referred to by [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189037%28VS.95%29.aspx) as **Move**. Refer to section to get a visual understanding of [Transformations and Coordinate Systems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189037(VS.95).aspx#transformcenter).

> Moves (translates) an element by the specified X  and Y  amounts.

[alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC212086.png](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC212086.png)

Comment: Thank you! I have posted my confusions about TranslateTransform and RenderTransformOrigin in EDIT 1 section of my post. Appreciate if you could let me know in order to understand the code I posted, what kinds of tutorials do I need to read?

Answer (score 7):

First of all translation does not use an origin so the `RenderTransformOrigin` does not apply to a `TranslateTransform`.

To learn about transforms why not try them out? Place a shape two times in a grid, and let the top one be transparent. Then transform the top shap and view the effect. Here I have rotated a rectangle by 45 degrees around the center of the rectangle.

```
<Grid Background="White">
  <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Black"/>
  <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Red" Opacity="0.5"
      RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
      <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
  </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

[image: RotateTransform]

Comment: Thank you! I am a newbie for Silverlight animation and I am maintaining code which is using TranslateTransform and RenderTransformOrigin. Appreciate if you could recommend me some good tutorials for a beginner of this area.

Comment: I have posted my confusions about TranslateTransform and RenderTransformOrigin in EDIT 1 section of my post. Appreciate if you could let me know in order to understand the code I posted, what kinds of tutorials do I need to read?